# How does Symfony internally sets the service name in @Route annotation?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I'm trying to emulate the behavior of [`Route`](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/Configuration/Route.php) Symfony annotation([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)), which extends `Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route` adding the `service` property:

```
class Route extends BaseRoute
{
    protected $service;

    public function setService($service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    // ...
}
```

It adds the `service` property in order to set the `_controller` parameter to `servicename:method` when controller is actually a service. This is done in the `AnnotatedRouteControllerLoader` class:

```
protected function configureRoute(Route $route, \ReflectionClass $class, 
    \ReflectionMethod $method, $annot)
{
    // ...
    if ($classAnnot && $service = $classAnnot->getService()) {
        $route->setDefault('_controller', $service.':'.$method->getName());
    } else {
        // Not a service ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

My question is how/when the `setService($service)` is invoked?

I've tried to define my custom `MyCustomRoute` annotation (with the above `service` property), loop each container service and call `setService($serviceId)` to "notify" that the controller is actually a service:

```
foreach ($container->getServiceIds() as $serviceId) {
    if ($container->hasDefinition($serviceId)) {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition($serviceId);
        $reflector = new \ReflectionClass($definition->getClass());

        // If the service is a controller then flag it for the 
        // AnnotatedRouteControllerLoader
        if ($annot = $reader->getClassAnnotation($reflector, 
            'My\CustomAnnotations\MyCustomRoute')) {
            $annot->setServiceName($serviceId);
        }
    }
}
```

Here `$container` is Symfony service container, `$reader` is doctrine annotation reader.

This is not working because annotation is read again in `AnnotatedRouteControllerLoader` **resulting in a different instance**, loosing the `service` property.

I'm using the routing component alone (without the entire Symfony framework).

Answer (score 0):

The Route class is declared as a service, refering to the doc, you can inject dependencies by controller, but also with "setter injection". take a look here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection

So you can declare your service as:

```
my_custom.router:
    class:     "Acme\MyBundle\MyServices\MyRouter"
    calls:
        - [setService, ["@service_key"]]
```